# A real life example of public properties being bad

Tags: java, oop, conventions

Countless times I've read that public properties on a class are a major faux pas, but I fail to see why on data that doesn't get transformed going in/out.

example of something I would write

```
public class Employee
{
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    private int ssn = 0;
    public boolean setSsn(String s)
    {
        //makes perfect sense why something like an ssn would use a getter setter
        //some code to validate ssn
        if(!validSsn(s)){
            ssn = 0; 
            return false;
        }
        ssn = raw;
        return true;
    }
    public String getSsn()
    {
        return ssn;
    }
    private boolean validSsn(String s)
    {
        //validation goes here
        retrun val;
    }

    //I don't understand why I should make firstName private
    // and then write
    public void setFirstName(String s)
    {
        firstName = s;
    }
    public String getFirstName(String s)
    {
        return firstName;
    }       
}
```

please provide a scenario in which this would cause a problem and please be specific, not "because it causes issues when other people use your code" WHY? Why does it cause issues. Thanks in advance for constructive criticism and detailed answers :D

Comment: What if you want to error check firstName as it gets set?  Or lock it after it is set.  You don't have any of that logic in your set methods, so your example wouldn't need it, but in some cases you may need that logic.

Comment: `employee.firstName = "\n";`

Comment: It's not that public properties are bad, it's that public ***fields*** break encapsulation and allow data to be changed without the class's knowledge . If you don't care about the values in the fields, it's not a big deal.  But if you are relying on them to be there or have certain  values in other methods, there is no way to enforce that with a field.

Comment: If the alternative to the public field is a plain setter/getter, then using a public field is essentially equivalent. See for example: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/97493/47845 and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/261868/47845

Comment: @dbugger huh - you can say the exact same thing about the setter in this case... So your comment doesn't really address the question.

Comment: In addition to what @FelixCastor said, you might not need to check a field value... _now_. But what if you need to check it in a later release? :)

Comment: @AndyThomas `employee.setFirstName("\n");` ?

Comment: @assylias, a plain setter yes, but it does not have to be a plain setter

Comment: @dbugger The question *is* about a plain setter....

Comment: @assylias - Today's plain setter can be changed tomorrow without affecting external callers. A public field cannot. They are not equivalent in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine that your code has gone to production.  I write a front-end that uses your Employee class that accesses `firstName` and `lastName` directly.

6 months go by, and now there's a new business requirement that you add validation to the name fields.

Where are you going to add it? You're going to have to make the fields private and add set methods, and this will force me and everyone else using your code to re-write our apps.

If you had encapsulated that data properly in the first place, all we'd have to do is recompile using the new version of the library with your code.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. However, wouldn't you have to catch the new exception anyway? Sure, you'd avoid changing the "setFirstName()" statement, but if the name is invalid, what are you going to do about it? Why can't Java have C# style get/set :'(

Comment: You could add fallback mechanisms, for instance not setting the fields in case of an error. Whatever that fallback may be, using setters and getters allows for much more flexibility as you actually HIDE the logic inside your class and provide a clean and nice interface. Public fields are just ugly.

Comment: @JesseAdam Since you've already got validation on the ssn field, I'm assuming I'd have already put a general "catch exception, display error, re-prompt user" mechanism in place.  There's no guarantee that I wouldn't have to touch the code again, but proper encapsulation takes very little effort to put a decent amount of future-proofing into your code.

Comment: @Hafnernuss lacking in future proof-ness? sure, but don't you dare call them ugly! Calling a method every time I want simple data is really ugly.

employee.setFirstName("Dave");  --I could get used to it
vs
employee.firstName = "Dave"; --still think it's cleaner
||||
print(employee.firstName) -- clean, minimal
vs
print(employee.getFirstName()) --this is what I hate

Comment: @JesseAdam well thats a matter of personal taste, I'll give you that. Personally when using C++, sometimes I write data structures that are only containers for data. In such cases im going with your approach, mainly because I'm lazy and its fast. But as soon as the class actually does something with the parameters i use getters and setters for the reasons mentioned. And, be honest, accessing the data via get/set is not even more effort in time of code size than using the fields directly.

Comment: @Hafnernuss To be clear, I agree with you completely on the technical concepts and in my original question I wrote get/set methods for ssn and now I understand the idea of future-proofing all properties. It's the getter method that drives me crazy because I like to think of properties as "hanging off" the object "employee.firstName" is clearly a variable, where as "employee.getFirstName()" feels like there's some kind of data manipulation or complex logic being called upon (even though I know there isn't)

Comment: @JesseAdam yes, but then you have to change your perception. I dont know if theres some kind of "contract" in any language, but getters usually don't do any data manipulation. (Initializing at most)